# Excel copy rows down to blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy rows that contain data (in cells A, B, C, D) down into the same cells (in the different rows) if the cells are blank. So basically copying the data in the above cells if the preceding cells are empty. The code I have is as follows:

```
Sub PadOut()
With Range("A2:D300") ' change this
  On Error Resume Next
  Set aRange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)  'check for blank cells
  On Error Goto 0
  If Not aRange Is Nothing Then   
     aRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"   
     .Value = .Value   
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Currently I have it at a set range.. But how can I set so as the range can be expanded (if I didn't know the number of total rows)

Comment: If there is a block of data without a fully empty row or column use `Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion`. See [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) for particulars.

Comment: Is there any condition to stop executing the code?

Comment: Good Question! The last row which has data in cells A, B, C, D filled data down a few more rows. How can I stop when it reaches the end.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?  You can change the start row and column number as neccessary.  The `endCol` variable defines the last colulmn to scan through and the `endRow` loop finds the last used row in the defined column range.

```
Sub PadOut()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim startRow As Long
    startRow = 2
    Dim startCol As Long
    startCol = 1
    Dim endCol As Long
    endCol = 3

    With ActiveSheet

        Dim row As Long
        Dim col As Long
        Dim endRow As Long

        Dim bottomRow As Long
        bottomRow = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
        Dim colEndRow As Long
        endRow = 0
        For col = startCol To endCol
            If (Cells(bottomRow, col).End(xlUp).row > endRow) Then
                endRow = Cells(bottomRow, col).End(xlUp).row
            End If
        Next col

        For col = startCol To endCol
            For row = startRow + 1 To endRow
                If .Cells(row, col).value = "" Then
                    .Cells(row, col).value = .Cells(row - 1, col).value
                End If
            Next row
        Next col

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Works great. But if the last if the last row contains data I want it to stop. It continues on a few more rows.

Comment: @user1766709 do you mean that the last row in a particular column isn't the last row in the sheet and you want it to stop there?  The code above should stop at the last used row in the sheet, check if it contains a value and copy the value above if it does not

Comment: @user1766709 do you have data in another column (not A, B, C or D) that extends past the last row of the first 4 columns?

Comment: When it reaches the last row (let's say row 1000) This row has values in the column but it copies the data in this row a further 10 rows. so rows 1000 to 1010 has the same data - I only needed it to stop at 1000 (in this case so still needs to be flexible)

Comment: @user1766709 `endRow` is set by the last row of data in the worksheet so the loop can't run past that.  Check the value stored in `lastRow` and make sure it's the last row of data, otherwise you must have data in another column that extends beyond columns A - D.

Comment: You are absolutely corrected. I had just figured out that. Thank you great iput.

Comment: @user1766709 I've modified it a little to only find the bottom used row within the limit of the column range you define with `startCol` and `endCol`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub PadOut()
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
if cells(lastRow, 1) = "" and cells(lastRow, 2) = "" and cells(lastRow, 3) = "" and cells(lastRow, 4) = "" then
  lastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(cells(lastRow, 1).end(xlup).row, cells(lastRow, 2).end(xlup).row, cells(lastRow, 3).end(xlUp).row, cells(lastRow, 4).end(xlup).row)
end if

With Range("A2:D" & lastRow)
  On Error Resume Next
  Set aRange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)  'check for blank cells
  On Error Goto 0
  If Not aRange Is Nothing Then   
     aRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"   
     .Value = .Value   
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total number of rows using the following:

```
numberRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Then you can set up the range accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need VBA for this task. 
It can be accomplished with use of the selection page and array filling.

To do this:
**Highlight your range**, starting with the first row and cell that has blank data you are interested in filling.
Next, **press CTRL+G**, this will display the "Go To" window, **press Special...**. **Select the "blanks" option and press OK.**
This will select all BLANK cells in your range. Then, without clicking (or you will change your selection), type:   **= {Press UP arrow} then press CTRL + ENTER**

*Your Data Before*        //          *Your Data After*

[image]
[image]